# KiCAD - "pin connected to other pins but not driven by any pin" GND

Tags: ground, kicad

When I perform the "electrical rule check" in KiCAD I get errors at my GND-Symbols.
`pin connected to other pins but not driven by any pin`

After googling I was presented the solution of going to a "pin property" menu.
Unfortunatelly I don't know how to get to that menu.
I only have the "property" menu  of the symbol and I cannot set the "power property" there.

I tried using the "power flag" symbol and the "GND_PWR" symbol but that also produces similar errors.

[image: GND problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding another GND-symbol that is only connected to a PWR_FLAG-symbol separately from the circuit.

[image: Solution]

Comment: The power flag will also work if it's connected to the GND net anywhere, it doesn't have to be separate.

Comment: @jfowkes You are right but I found out that this only works if the power flag is very close to the GND symbol otherwise it seems to get connected to the wire or the next symbol.